# Line number during cross-referencing. No Line number appears

Tags: cross-referencing

I read these two questions: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225178/line-number-in-cross-reference), but I am still in a trouble.

So, I have two files:

**test1.tex**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} 
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\begin{document}
    \linenumbers  % enable line numbering
    \lipsum[1-6]
    \\ \\
    \label{important}IMPORTANT INFORMATION
    \\ \\
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

and **test2.tex**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{test1}
\begin{document}
    Important information was given on line \ref{important} of page~\pageref{important}.
\end{document}
```

But line number did not appear.
**Could you help me to have referencing with line number?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357517/4736

Comment: This gives me an absolute line number(54) but not 13 from page.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer with `\ref` to the number of a line, which has been marked with `\linelabel{lne:item}`. The command `\lineref` does something completely different, see the manual.

So you get your reference with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} 
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\begin{document}
    \linenumbers  % enable line numbering
    \lipsum[1-6]

    \linelabel{lne:important}IMPORTANT INFORMATION

    \lipsum[1-6]

    The IMPORTANT INFORMATION ist given in line no. \ref{lne:important} on page
    \pageref{lne:important}

\end{document}
```

The result ist something like »The IMPORTANT INFORMATION ist given in line no. 12 on page 2« in the PDF.